# AWS Athena Nested JSON error

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a nested JSON file that looks like below:

```
\n  \"total\" : 510,\n  \"start\" : 0,\n  \"count\" : 500,\n  \"data\" : [ {\n    \"id\" : 294,\n    \"candidate\" : {\n      \"id\" : 5275,\n      \"firstName\" : \"bob\",\n      \"lastName\" : \"bob\"\n    },\n    \"sendingUser\" : {\n      \"id\" : 5,\n      \"firstName\" : \"tom\",\n      \"lastName\" : \"tom\"\n    },\n    \"dateAdded\" : 1487865908960,\n    \"jobOrder\" : {\n      \"id\" : 71,\n      \"title\" : \"Job\"\n    },\n    \"status\" : \"1st Interview\",\n    \"_score\" : 1.0\n  }
```

I have this stored in S3 and am trying to create a table in AWS Athena, the editor I have done is below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cvtest (
  data struct < candidate struct <id string, firstName string, lastName string>,
                sendingUser struct <id string, firstName string, lastName string>,
                dateAdded string,
                jobOrder string,
                score string
              > 
  )           
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://es-cvsent';
```

But the query runs into an error below;

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:26 missing : at 'struct' near '<EOF>' line 2:37 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 2:55 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 2:72 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 3:28 missing : at 'struct' near '<EOF>' line 3:39 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 3:57 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 3:74 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 4:26 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 5:25 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>' line 6:22 missing : at 'string' near '<EOF>'

This query ran against the "test" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 84e876e8-b947-490e-b2b6-7bf9c376266e.
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't valid JSON, and isn't valid "nested" JSON, either. How did this get into its current condition?  It looks like it may have been plucked from a larger JSON structure using string manipulation instead of being deserialized with a JSON parser... and you simply can't do that and end up with parsable content.  It looks like a leading `"{` and a trailing `}"` are missing, which would make it a valid *JSON string containing a JSON object* but still not a valid *JSON object* overall, so the solution will likely be more complicated than just that.

Comment: Thanks Michael, The line is the first extract of the JSON file I have. the file includes another 500 lines within the data struct. But your point makes sense. The JSON was created by a python script that calls a REST API and puts then uses JSON dump to dump the file. Maybe the answer is looking here at the output formatting. As when you view the file it is all on one line unlike a traditional JSON.

Comment: If you are getting a "file" that already contains JSON, you need to either just save the file -- not "using" JSON (again, because it's already JSON) -- or you need to decode the original JSON from the API and then re-encode it when saving.  Your final file needs to be a clean, complete JSON object, and shoudn't contain any "nested" JSON.  Suggestion: write a little script to verify that you can open the files you are creating again and decode the JSON yourself.  If you can't, then Athena can't, either.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I took the double encoding out and wrote the url response direct as a JSON into s3. When I print it prints as you would expect JSON. Sample below:  {
    "id" : 467,
    "candidate" : {
      "id" : 8077,
      "firstName" : "Bob",
      "lastName" : "Bob"
    },
    "sendingUser" : {
      "id" : 7566,
      "firstName" : "Bob",
      "lastName" : "Bob"
    },
    "dateAdded" : 1498550860320,
    "jobOrder" : {
      "id" : 5,
      "title" : "Job"
    },
    "status" : "Shortlisted",
    "_score" : 1.0
  },

Comment: can I use this in this format?

Comment: That looks much better to me.  The comma at the end of the line wouldn't be correct for a standalone object, but if this is part of a larger document, it may be fine.  See if it works.

Comment: so the eror has no changed toFAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Comment: The above is fixed as I missed / on end of location. I now have a successful query. but not correctly formatted it all appears in one field under data

Answer (score 0):

The data itself doesn't look like a valid JSON, but regardless of that you should be able to create a table because the underlying data is not validated at this point in time. (Just querying the table afterwards wouldn't work).

The problem you are having is that your syntax is wrong, see [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/).":" is used between column and datatype within the struct definition.

This should work

```
data struct<candidate:struct<id:string, firstName:string, lastName:string>,
                sendingUser:struct<id:string, firstName:string, lastName:string>,
                dateAdded:string,
                jobOrder:string,
                score:string
              >
```